# Using PerfIt with Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy (i.e. Castle.Core) not working

Tags: autofac, interceptor, performancecounter

Using C# .NET on Windows 7.

I want to instrument some methods in my service workers to record some performance counters. The best way I have found to do that, IMO, is PerfIt.

I am also using Autofac as my DI container. This decision was made before PerfIt in my application service. That's background, not up for discussion here at the moment.

PerfIt uses Castle.Core IInterceptor at its core, for which I want to use Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy. Or if there's a better instrumentation choice, and/or roll my own, I'm open to it.

I register my interceptor with Autofac:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = // ...

builder.RegisterType<WorkerInterceptor>()
    .OnActivated(args =>
    {
        var instance = args.Instance;
        instance.PublishCounters = true;
        instance.PublishEvent = true;
        instance.RaisePublishErrors = true;
        instance.SamplingRate = 1d;
    })
    .SingleInstance();
```

I also register the worker for which key methods are instrumented.

```
builder.RegisterType<PuzzleProblemSolverWorker>()
    .As<IServiceWorker>()
    .As<IPuzzleProblemSolverWorker>()
    .InstancePerDependency()
    .InterceptedBy(typeof(WorkerInterceptor));
```

And the instrumented method is:

```
[PerfIt("PuzzleService", InstanceName = "PuzzleProblemSolverWorker")]
public virtual bool ShouldSaveSolution(byte[] bytes)
{
    // ... Calculated whether shouldSave ...
    return shouldSave;
}
```

The instrumented method is in fact being called, verified by breakpoints. However, I am not seeing any evidence that the instrumentation is working.

My confusion is, there is enough of a confluence between PerfIt and/or Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy, not sure which is failing to see the other, and/or the worker, but something is obviously falling through the cracks.

Individually, both tests are passing within their respective projects. But do not seem to be seeing one another via my Autofac container. I wouldn't be surprised if it was a Reflection BindingFlags issue or something like that, but I wonder if anyone has seen something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `EnableClassInterceptors` call on the `PuzzleProblemSolverWorker` registration.

The example [from the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) shows this:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
   .EnableClassInterceptors()
   .InterceptedBy(typeof(CallLogger));
```

So if you update to this...

```
builder.RegisterType<PuzzleProblemSolverWorker>()
  .As<IServiceWorker>()
  .As<IPuzzleProblemSolverWorker>()
  .InstancePerDependency()
  .EnableClassInterceptors()
  .InterceptedBy(typeof(WorkerInterceptor));
```

...you should have more luck.

Comment: Thank you for following up. Since I'd explored PerfIt with some interest, there were some nuances that I needed better exposure, so I took the liberty of rolling an offering of my own. Feel free to have a look [here](http://github.com/mwpowellhtx/MeasureIt/) if you're interested.